# Reset Heroku DB now some of my schemas aren't migrating

Tags: django, heroku

New to heroku - I had some major problems with a migration from my local django app to Heroku prod so decided to destroy my heroku db with `heroku pg:reset` - this all seemed to go to plan, I then ran `heroku run python manage.py migrate` to attempt to recreate my schemas.

The following were migrated:

```
  Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, sites, socialaccount
```

But none of my `models.py` tables went up - eg the following crucial schema was not migrated:

```
class mapCafes(models.Model): 
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    cafe_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cafe_address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cafe_long = models.FloatField()
    cafe_lat = models.FloatField()
    geolocation = models.PointField(geography=True, blank=True, null=True)
    venue_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cafe_image_url = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)

    # class Meta:
    #     # managed = False

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cafe_name
```

Installed Apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.gis',

    'testingland',
    'rest_framework',
    'bootstrap_modal_forms',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'widget_tweaks',
]
```

Any advice?

Comment: Did you add the application where you model is located to `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Hey thanks - I added ``INSTALLED_APPS`` to OP - do I need to re-push the app?

Comment: Do makemigrations then direct migrate from commant line

Comment: Yes, you'll also need to repush the app, because INSTALLED_APPS is used to generate URL routing etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response @NicoGriffioen - when I run ``git push heroku main`` I receive: ``Everything up-to-date``